# Signalr Hub in Separate Dll

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I had a hub hosted in a console app with a WPF app connecting to it. It worked just fine. Then I moved the hub into a separate project and added a reference from the host to new project. Now I am getting a 500 error, with  no other details.

Is there anything different that needs to be done in order to host a hub from another assemble/namespace?

Edit:
I tried a few things after opening the question. Here is what I have tried so far:

- Setting the HubName attribute. - Did not work.
- Passing the full    namespace + class into
  HubConnection.CreateHubProxy. - Did not work.
- Putting my hub class into the same project but a different namespace. - This worked.

Here is the exception that gets passed back.
"System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Http.HttpHelper.<>c_*DisplayClass2.b*_0(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)"

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me (in startup)

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(typeof(MyHub).Assembly.FullName);
```

Credits to [map hubs in referenced project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16779057/map-hubs-in-referenced-project)

Answer (score 0):

Try to see the http response message

```
        try
        {
            hubConnection.Start().Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            if (error.InnerException is WebException)
            {
                WebException webError = (WebException)error.InnerException;
                Console.WriteLine(webError.Status);
                Console.WriteLine(webError.Response);
            }
        }
```

Comment: That writes out:
ProtocolError
System.Net.HttpWebResponse

Answer (score 0):

Have you moved your call to register your hubs to the new dll?  I.e. the following needs to be in your new project (but still called from global.asax):

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
```

You probably also need to use the [WebActivator PreApplicationStart attribute] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.preapplicationstartmethodattribute.aspx) in the new RegisterHubs class to ensure it is registered in time

Comment: The call to MapHubs is still present in the host. I know that the Hub is being registered before the first call because I am starting the host before starting the client.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, it seems I didn't reed your question properly at all.  Let me have a think

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the separate DLL has a reference to `Microsoft.CSharp.dll` - which is required for `dynamic` code.