# How do I make a SignalR external reference to hub and not perform circular reference?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr, hangfire

So, I'm trying to create a sample where there are the following components/features:

- A hangfire server OWIN self-hosted from a Windows Service
- SignalR notifications when jobs are completed

[Github Project](https://github.com/kfrancis/signalr-hangfire)

I can get the tasks queued and performed, but I'm having a hard time sorting out how to then notify the clients (all currently, just until I get it working well) of when the task/job is completed.

My current issue is that I want the SignalR hub to be located in the "core" library [SampleCore](https://github.com/kfrancis/signalr-hangfire/tree/master/source/SampleCore), but I don't see how to "register it" when starting the webapp [SampleWeb](https://github.com/kfrancis/signalr-hangfire/tree/master/source/SampleWeb). One way I've gotten around that is to create a hub class [NotificationHubProxy](https://github.com/kfrancis/signalr-hangfire/blob/master/source/SampleWeb/NotificationHubProxy.cs) that inherits the actual hub and that works fine for simple stuff (sending messages from one client to all).

In [NotifyTaskComplete](https://github.com/kfrancis/signalr-hangfire/blob/master/source/SampleCore/TaskRunner.cs#L26), I believe I can get the hub context and then send the message like so:

```
private void NotifyTaskComplete(int taskId)
    {
        try
        {
            var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();
            if (hubContext != null)
            {
                hubContext.Clients.All.sendMessage(string.Format("Task {0} completed.", taskId));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

BUT, I can't do that if NotificationHubProxy is the class being used as it's part of the SampleWeb library and referencing it from SampleCore would lead to a circular reference.

I know the major issue is the hub in the external assembly, but I can't for the life of me find a relevant sample that's using SignalR or MVC5 or setup in this particular way.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the solution was to do the following two things:

1. I had to use the SignalR .NET client from the SampleCore assembly to create a HubConnection, to create a HubProxy to "NotificationHub" and use that to Invoke the "SendMessage" method - like so:

   ```
   private void NotifyTaskComplete(string hostUrl, int taskId)
   {
       var hubConnection = new HubConnection(hostUrl);
       var hub = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("NotificationHub");
       hubConnection.Start().Wait();
       hub.Invoke("SendMessage", taskId.ToString()).Wait();
   }
   ```

BUT, as part of creating that HubConnection - I needed to know the url to the OWIN instance. I decided to pass that a parameter to the task, retrieving it like:

```
private string GetHostAddress()
{
    var request = this.HttpContext.Request;
    return string.Format("{0}://{1}", request.Url.Scheme, request.Url.Authority);
}
```

2. The solution to having a Hub located in an external assembly is that the assembly needs to be loaded before the SignalR routing is setup, like so:

   ```
   AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(typeof(SampleCore.NotificationHub).Assembly.FullName);
   app.MapSignalR();
   ```

This solution for this part came from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16779057/map-hubs-in-referenced-project).