# JQuery 3 and SignalR 2.2.0

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I use SignalR 2.2.0 in a MVC5 project. SignalR depends of JQuery in client-side.

JQuery recently released new version, I updated it from Nuget, specifically from version 2.2.4 to 3.0.0.1, but then SignalR stopped working. Startup command "$.connection.hub" in javascript fails.
After a long time head scratching, I downgrade JQuery to 2.2.4 and everything is fine again.

Am I the only one getting this problem? There is any workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm having the same problem; but worse. Upgrading jQuery from 1.11.x to 3.4.1. Have many breaking changes and most of them are coming from other dependencies

Comment: @SenuraDissanayake Try upgrading everything... Now I'm currently using SignalR 2.4.1 and still JQuery 3.3.1, got no problems upgrading since that one.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Finally version 2.2.1 of SignalR was released, solving this problem. Thanks for all comments.

Comment: interestingly no mention of jQuery 3 in the release notes but here they are anyway : https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/releases

Comment: looking at jquery.signalR-2.2.1.js. I still find jQuery.fn.unbind() for example. I don't think that singalR 2.2.1 is yet fully ready for jquery 3

Comment: Version 2.2.2 seems to cure this, its compatible with Jquery 3.1.1 as it comes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for documenting your solution! I spent 4 days full-time to investigate the issue... Originally I assumed, the server-side is broken.

Answer (score 21):

You must edit the signalR code by yourself, In jquery 3 they removed the shortcut for load event :

> **Breaking change: .load(), .unload(), and .error() removed**
>
> These methods are shortcuts for event operations, but had several API
> limitations. The event .load() method conflicted with the ajax .load()
> method. The .error() method could not be used with window.onerror
> because of the way the DOM method is defined. If you need to attach
> events by these names, use the .on() method, e.g. change
> $("img").load(fn) to $(img).on("load", fn).

https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/

so in the file `jquery.signalR-{version}.js` :

you must update this line :

```
_pageWindow.load(function () { _pageLoaded = true; });
```

To :

```
_pageWindow.on("load",function () { _pageLoaded = true; });
```

Comment: Worked for me, also.

Comment: SignalR developers must make this change now.

Comment: I had this problem in version 1.2.2 and this worked for me. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're still getting errors like this after updating to `2.2.1` and jQuery 3.x then read on...

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined
```

Like I am you are probably using the [dynamically generated proxy](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#dynamicproxy), and you checked your `/signalr/hubs` file and found you don't have any proxies defined.

```
 var proxies = {};
```

Wait you may ask I didn't change anything - where did they go?

Well, like me you probably were in such a hurry to upgrade signalR to `2.2.1` that you forgot to do it in all your projects and now you are using both `2.2.1` and `2.2.0` in different assemblies. (I am defining my hubs in a different assembly than my main app).

All I needed to do was make sure I had the latest nuget package version in every project and it all worked. Should work fine after rebuilding.  [If not, this may also help.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16779057/map-hubs-in-referenced-project%60)

Also do yourself a favor and read the [jQuery 3 upgrade guide](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/) if you use much jQuery elsewhere.