# Error: SignalR: SignalR is not loaded. Please ensure jquery.signalR-x.js is referenced before ~/signalr/js

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, signalr

I have an existing setup (from 2014) using Crossroads, Hasher, Knockout all works fine and I am using RequireJS to load all dependencies.

I have tried to incorporate SignalR into the mix and having issues with the error: SignalR: SignalR is not loaded. Please ensure jquery.signalR-x.js is referenced before ~/signalr/js.

All my references seem to be in the correct order and all script items seem to load see picture:[NetworkTab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnrKd.png)

This is my requireJS:

```
var require = {
baseUrl: ".",
paths: {
    "bootstrap":            "bower_modules/components-bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min",
    "crossroads":           "bower_modules/crossroads/dist/crossroads.min",
    "hasher":               "bower_modules/hasher/dist/js/hasher.min",
    "jquery":               "bower_modules/jquery/dist/jquery",
    "knockout":             "bower_modules/knockout/dist/knockout",
    "knockout-projections": "bower_modules/knockout-projections/dist/knockout-projections",
    "signals":              "bower_modules/js-signals/dist/signals.min",
    "text":                 "bower_modules/requirejs-text/text",

"signalr": "bower_modules/signalr/jquery.signalR",
"signalr.hubs": "http://localhost:50660/signalr/hubs?"
},
shim: {

    "jquery": {
        exports: "$"
    },
    "bootstrap": { deps: ["jquery"] },

    "signalr": {
        "deps": ["jquery"],
        "exports": "$.connection"
    },
    "signalr.hubs": {
        "deps": ["signalr"]
    }

}
};
```

and this is my programme-grid.js:

```
define(['knockout', 'text!./programme-grid.html'], function (ko, template) {

function ProgrammeGridViewModel(params) {

    this.channels = ko.observableArray([]);

    $.getJSON('http://localhost:50660/api/Task/Get', this.channels);

}

return { viewModel: ProgrammeGridViewModel, template: template };
});

require(["jquery", "signalr.hubs"]),
function ($) {
var connection = $.hubConnection("http://localhost:50660/signalr");
connection.logging = true;

connection.error(function (error) {
    //this shows error but commented out for now
    alert('SignalR error: ' + error)
});
}
```

and this is my index.html:

```
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">   
      <title>Title</title>
      <link href="bower_modules/components-bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="app/require.config.js"></script>
      <script data-main="app/startup" src="bower_modules/requirejs/require.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav-bar params="route: route"></nav-bar>
    <div id="page" class="container" data-bind="component: { name: route().page, params: route }"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I have missed any code or markup please let me know and I will provide this. I have setup SignalR in the past and not had any problems however I have just started to use RequireJS so not sure what I have done is half correct.

Thanks

Nick

Comment: The problem comes from jquery, signalr must be updated to use jquery 3 :http://stackoverflow.com/a/37988115/5703316

Comment: @QuentinRoger that doesn't seem to have worked.

Comment: @QuentinRoger a million apologies, that has resolved that particular issue. Now cannot load hubs file but the link to the hubs file opens fine.

Comment: @QuentinRoger how can I make your first comment an answer even though it was just a comment?