# SignalR version 1.2.2 getting Error: The controller for path '/function () { _pageLoaded = true; }' was not found or does not implement IController

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I am using SignalR version 1.2.2 with ASP.NET MVC 4.  I set the signalR connections to a page inside a defined "Area"  Regardless though, this seems to come at the SignalR script load. Because if I access a view defined in the main area outside of the areas sections, I still get this error:

> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The controller for path '/function () { _pageLoaded = true; }' was not found or does not implement IController.
>      at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

I found, `/function () { _pageLoaded = true; }` inside jquery.signalR-1.2.2.js as `_pageWindow.load(function () { _pageLoaded = true; });`

I have followed this tutorial: [Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/older-versions/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-aspnet-signalr) which uses a singleton to maintain a instance of the Context for the hub.  what could I be doing wrong?

Update: when I remove the script reference to the SignalR js file from the head the error goes away, so I can confidently say it is SignalR related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, looks like it's because of my later version of JQuery: [JQuery 3 and SignalR 2.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37952332/jquery-3-and-signalr-2-2-0)

Updating:

_pageWindow.load(function () { _pageLoaded = true; });

To :

_pageWindow.on("load",function () { _pageLoaded = true; });

inside the jquery.singalR file solved my problem.