# SignalR Service mock implementation for Service/Integration testing

Tags: testing, service, signalr, integration

I want to be able to simulate SignalR Hub for services tests. The idea is to be able to create a test in the following way:
Start a SignalR server (url, port and hub class should be configured at runtime) - the hub will be created in the test module for this purpose.
So the first part - starting a runtime configurable SignalR server Is possible:

```
StartOptions so = new StartOptions("http://127.0.0.1:8080");
so.AppStartup = "SrServer.Startup1"; // set the startup class (will be defined in the test module)
```

The following is an example for Startup1:

```
class Startup1
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```

The only issue I'm missing is being able to set the hub to be used from my test module - is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Just load the assembly that contains the hub before calling 'app.MapSignalR();'

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(typeof(MyHub).Assembly.FullName);
```

Source:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21597197/10720979

Comment: I'm looking for a way to set a hub per configuration (webapp) if possible to bypass Hub searches by reflection (specifying explicitly which hub is to be used)